# MFMailViewComposer does not return an error when writing a wrong target address format

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

When I try to send an email to a non-existing address (for example, "hello"), MFMail Composer should return MFMailComposeResultFailed, I guess, but this does not occur, and the message seems to be sent correctly (obviously, it is not sent). I tried the same with "Mail" and in this case, "Mail" answers that there has been an error sending the message, however, when I do the same in my app, there are no errors. How can I fix this?

This is the code I use when I get into the mail screen:

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
    mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailer setSubject:@"Notification"];
    User *user = [user_array objectAtIndex:0];
      NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:user.eMail, nil];
      [mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients];

    [mailer setMessageBody:self.label1.text isHTML:NO];
    [self presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:nil];
    [mailer release];
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failure"
                                                    message:@"Your device doesn't support the composer sheet"
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

}

and this is the code for the responder:

```
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {
NSString *string = @"";
switch (result)
{
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        string = @"cancelled";
        NSLog(@"Mail cancelled: you cancelled the operation and no email message was queued.");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        NSLog(@"Mail saved: you saved the email message in the drafts folder.");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        string = @"sent";
        NSLog(@"Mail send: the email message is queued in the outbox. It is ready to send.");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        NSLog(@"Mail failed: the email message was not saved or queued, possibly due to an error.");
        break;
    default:
        NSLog(@"Mail not sent.");
        break;
}
// Remove the mail view
int abc = MFMailComposeErrorCodeSendFailed;
NSLog(@"ERROR LOG %i", abc);
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
if ([string isEqualToString:@"cancelled"]) {
    ViewController *second = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Notif_detail"];
    [second setString1:self.string1];
    [second setString2:self.string2];
    [second setString3:self.string3];
    [second setString4:self.string4];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];
}
else if ([string isEqualToString:@"sent"]){

    ViewController *second = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View"];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];
}
```

}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please add some code? It's impossible to say what is wrong with just a description of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there is actually no error when `didFinishWithResult` gets triggered, because the message is queued and is about to be sent. The error occurs at a later point of time when you get response from the mail server (smtp code) due to not delivered message.

Comment: Yes iDroid, you are right, that's exactly what it happens, but how can I handle this error within my app? Thank you

Comment: You can't as it's none of your business. If you want that kind of control, you will have to implement your own way of sending mail or at least check validity of e-mail address format *before* presenting the composer.

Comment: yeah Flip, I think I will try checking manually the format of the input e-mail address. Thank you all!